# Fundapter - How to manipulate the view/layout

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to manipulate the view inside BindDictionary()?

Or how can I add an click event for a image view for instance? Can I do this inside BindDictionar()?

The library in which i'm trying to accomplish this is [Fun Dapter](https://github.com/amigold/FunDapter)

Answer (score 0):

You can do onClick in BindDictionary() by adding .onClick(... after for example .addStringField(res,met).onClick(

Here is a full example:

```
BindDictionary<SomeObject> dict = new BindDictionary<SomeObject>();

dict.addStringField(R.id.time, new StringExtractor<SomeObject>() {

            @Override
            public String getStringValue(SomeObjectitem, int position) {                
                return item.getSomething();

            }
        }).onClick(new ItemClickListener<SomeObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(SomeObjectitem, int position, View view) {
            }
        });
```

**Edit.**
The second possibility is to edit the fundapter libary yourself.

First create a new interface in com.ami.fundapter.interfaces:

```
package com.ami.fundapter.interfaces;

import android.widget.TextView;

public interface TextViewExtractor {
    public void getTextView(String string, TextView view);
}
```

Then in BindDictionary create this method:

```
 public StringField<T> addStringField(int viewResId, StringExtractor<T> extractor,TextViewExtractor viewExtractor) {

        StringField<T> field = new StringField<T>(viewResId, extractor,viewExtractor);

        mStringFields.add(field);

        return field;
    }
```

After that in FunDapterUtils edit this method till it looks like this:

```
private static <T> void handleStringFields(T item, GenericViewHolder holder, int position,
                                           BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
    // handle string fields
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.getStringFields().size(); i++) {
        StringField<T> field = dictionary.getStringFields().get(i);
        String stringValue = field.extractor.getStringValue(item, position);
        TextView view = holder.stringFields[i];
    // fill data
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue) && view != null &&field.viewExtractor!=null){
        field.viewExtractor.getTextView(stringValue, view);
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue) && view != null) {
        view.setText(stringValue);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        view.setVisibility(field.visibilityIfNull);
    }

    // set textcolor if needed
    if (field.conditionalTextColorEntry != null) {
        boolean condition =
                field.conditionalTextColorEntry.getKey().getBooleanValue(item, position);

        if (condition) {
            view.setTextColor(field.conditionalTextColorEntry.getValue()[0]);
        } else {
            view.setTextColor(field.conditionalTextColorEntry.getValue()[1]);
        }
    }

    setClickListener(item, position, field, view);
}
```

}

And finally in StringField class create this method:

```
public StringField(int viewResId, StringExtractor<T> extractor,TextViewExtractor viewExtractor) {
        super(viewResId, extractor);
        this.viewExtractor = viewExtractor;
    }
```

And now you can do something like this:

```
BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
dict.addStringField(R.id.oldPrice, new StringExtractor<Product>() {

            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
                return item.getSomething();
            }
        },new TextViewExtractor() {

            @Override
            public void getTextView(String string, TextView view) {
                view.setPaintFlags(view.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG); //for example strikethrough text
            }


        });
```